# Using variables in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I just want to open a webpage providing an URL. My code is:

```
 void openURL(char const *message)
{   

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:message]];
}
```

And the error I get is:

```
 cannot initialize a parameter of type 'NSString *' with an lvalue of type 'const char *'
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:message]];
```

I am not familiar with Objective-C nor learning it. I just need to use this simple code in a project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to convert `message` to `NSString`, like this:

```
void openURL(char const *message)
{   
    NSString *messageStr = [NSString stringWithCString:message 
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:messageStr]];
}
```

Another solution is to pass `NSString` (this wold require constructing `NSString`s in all places where `openURL` is called:

```
void openURL(NSString *message)
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:message]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert char array to nsstring object first and then make url of that string.
likebelow:- 
void openURL(char const *message)
{

NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:sizeof(message) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:s]];
}